# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in an if statement in a function

Tags: python, typeerror

```
print(f'{R_max[0]} {R_min[0]}' )        # output 109 103
print(f'{r1_min} {r1_max}' )            # output 105 109
if R_max[0] <= r1_max + 1 and R_max[0] >= r1_max - 1:
    if R_min[0] >= r1_min - 1 and R_min[0] <= r1_min + 1:
        return 1, 0
```

I got error (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable) for calling one of my functions. After adding some print() function, I found the error is thrown by the above code. It's line 4, second *if* statement. I really cannot figure out what is going wrong here.
BTW, all the four variable involved are integers.

Comment: you are returning two values. Are you receiving these into a list?

Comment: Always post the full traceback.

Comment: Post function and its call method line also.

Comment: thanks you guys for your fast response. I've found the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the cause: I have a few *if* statement, in each of which my function returns 2 values. However, there are conditions that are not caught by all *if* or *else* statements,  meaning in those conditions my function does not return anything. That's why Python throws that error. After I add a final *return* statement at the end of the function, the error is gone.

Comment: That thrown error message is really no good for debugging.